# how I fill a list with many variables python

Tags: python

I have a some variables and I need to compare each of them and fill three lists according the comparison, if the `var == 1` add a `1` to `lista_a`, if `var == 2` add a `1` to `lista_b`..., like:

```
inx0=2 inx1=1 inx2=1 inx3=1 inx4=4 inx5=3 inx6=1 inx7=1 inx8=3 inx9=1
inx10=2 inx11=1 inx12=1 inx13=1 inx14=4 inx15=3 inx16=1 inx17=1 inx18=3 inx19=1
inx20=2 inx21=1 inx22=1 inx23=1 inx24=2 inx25=3 inx26=1 inx27=1 inx28=3 inx29=1

lista_a=[]
lista_b=[]
lista_c=[]

#this example is the comparison for the first variable inx0
#and the same for inx1, inx2, etc...
for k in range(1,30):
    if inx0==1:
        lista_a.append(1)
    elif inx0==2:
        lista_b.append(1)
    elif inx0==3:
        lista_c.append(1)
```

I need get:

```
#lista_a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
#lista_b = [1,1,1]
#lista_c = [1]
```

Comment: You shouldn't be creating all of those variables to begin with. You almost certainly want a dict or a list instead.

Comment: Note that your first three lines in your example will result in syntax errors; you cannot simply put assignments on one line like that. You would have to put them on separate lines, or use (shudder) semicolons between them.

Comment: (counting something with a list of `1`s instead of an `int` is almost certainly a Bad Idea too)

Comment: To expand on @Wooble's comment, whenever you start creating a bunch of variables with some kind of intelligent suffix to differentiate them, it is almost always going to be more cleanly implemented as a dict (or even just a list if the suffixes are all numbers in a range like from 0-29, say).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inx* variables should almost certinaly be a list to begin with:

```
inx = [2,1,1,1,4,3,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,4,3,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,3,1]
```

Then, to find out how many 2's it has:

```
inx.count(2)
```

If you must, you can build a new list out of that:

```
list_a = [1]*inx.count(1)
list_b = [1]*inx.count(2)
list_c = [1]*inx.count(3)
```

but it seems silly to keep a list of ones.  Really the only data you need to keep is a single integer (the count), so why bother carrying around a list?

---

An alternate approach to get the lists of ones would be to use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for item in inx:
    d[item].append(1)
```

in this case, what you want as `list_a` could be accessed by `d[1]`, `list_b` could be accessed as `d[2]`, etc.

---

Or, as stated in the comments, you could get the counts using a `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter #python2.7+
counts = Counter(inx)
list_a = [1]*counts[1]
list_b = [1]*counts[2]
...
```

Comment: or use `collections.Counter`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- Yeah, that would work to get the counts on python2.7+.

Comment: Yes... the variables are statistics data from database... thanks, your solution is more useful!